# Multilanguage website get the title, on different languages

Tags: get-the-title, plugin-polylang

I am working on a website, and I am using Polylang to translate it to a different language.
In my code I want to get a page title, and display it. My issue is I cannot get it by ID or page_by_path because its going to display the English version of the page on every language.

For example: I want to display the Contact page title on english Contact and on another language its equivalent translated contact page title.

Is there a way to do that?

The code that I'm using so far:

```
<?php $page = get_page_by_path( 'contact' ); ?>
<span><?php echo get_the_title( $page ); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In polylang you can use the function `pll_get_post($postID)` to get the id of the translated page like this:

`<?php echo get_the_title(pll_get_post(52)); ?>`

I'd be glad if you rate my answer if it was useful.

Comment: Huge thank you Rene it was exactly what I wanted!